# Non-object error when inadvertently loading view from app/storage/views/?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a Laravel 4 application that is configured to use the `file` `$_SESSION` driver, which appears to be causing some problems for me. The problem arises randomly, and does not happen very often, and tends to happen when I try and click on an `<a href="...">` quickly before the entire page is done loading (there is a large amount of information loaded on each page so page loads can be a bit slow). The error will also appear at times after waiting for the page to load completely.

Here is the error message I'm getting:

[image]

From what I understand, it looks like whenever my application decides it wants to load a (cached?) view from `app/storage/views`, it is not is not grabbing one or more of the objects that is passed to the view from my controller, and that is why I am getting a non-object error message.

I have tried experimenting by deleting the specific storage view in both the controller before the view is loaded and in the actual view itself (in `app/views`) with the following:

```
<?php

    $badFile1 = storage_path() . '/views/d84ddef7152ff1956fc7aa87ddf29ba0';
    if(file_exists($badFile1))
    {
        $delete = unlink($badFile1);
    }

?>
```

But even this will still throw the error (although without showing the line #) from the file in `app/storage/views`, even though the file doesn't even exist:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: This is a new one on me. Are the permissions all correct for your storage folder and its contents?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the views, file permissions etc. It says clearly that you're tring to call `$getID()` on non-object, probably `null`. So instead make sure that variable is the object you want or add some check before trying to output it.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk is right. Maybe we can help you if you show the code that `make`s the view and passes the data.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you `$catalog` object is null. so not called `getID()` method.

Please check, `$catalog` object is assigned or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem, as in, I have not been able to reproduce this random error message anymore.

It seems the error was caused by getting my models code tangled up, and not by `$catalogs` being `null`. I had two models:

`Suggestions.php` which does some data manipulation and `Catalogs.php` which ultimately fetches the `$catalogs` object which I needed for my view.

I was grabbing `$catalogs` like this in my controller:

```
$s = new Suggestions();
$catalogs = $s->getSuggestions($catalogID);
```

and then returning `$catalogs` in my view. The problem arises from the fact that I was also calling the `Catalogs.php` model (which contains the `getID()` function) from within the `Suggestions.php` model, and was not even instantiating a new instance of `Catalogs` to do so, just calling it straight away.

So most of the time Laravel would return `$catalogs` as an object of the `Catalogs` model like I wanted it to, but it would sometimes return it as an object of the `Suggestions` model, and when my view tried to call the `getID()` method, it was trying to call a method that did not exist in `Suggestions` model.

I fixed this by refactoring the `Suggestions` model into a private function as opposed to the model, that way `$catalogs` is always returning as the `Catalogs` object type.